# Why does *ngIf and [hidden] work differently for re-evaluating parent > child property bindings

Tags: angular

I have a component where in the template I include another component with inputs bound like so:

```
<div *ngIf="showComponent">
    <child-component
        [myInput]="someProperty"
        (onUpdate)="onUpdate($event)">
    </child-component>
</div>
```

As you can see the child component is housed inside another element which has an `*ngIf` applied.

When the child component is first shown the value of `someProperty` is reflected fine inside where its used in the child components template.

An action occurs in the child template that will update the value of the `someProperty` in the parent template.

The visibility of the child component can be toggled, when its hidden and shown again, it does not reflect the last updated value of `someProperty` for the parent component.

If I change the `*ngIf` to a `[hidden]`, it works perfectly. Is this the correct approach I should be using here? I am just worried of introducing anti patterns, so thought I would check with the community!

**EDIT**

I understand the differences between ngIf and [hidden] in terms of what happens in the DOM. I am just not understanding why when using ngIf and the child component is rendered between show/hide actions that its not pulling in the latest value of someProperty from my parent component that it lives in.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @mindparse, *ngIf is structural directive which modifies and/or deletes DOM node. so when we use *ngIf , it completely removes node from DOM if condition is false and renders node again if condition is true, While [hidden] doesn't removes node but just set the display properly of that element.

Comment: We prefer *ngIf instead of [hidden], as per the above explanation. Might be wrap the update logic in parent component with SetTimeout(()=>{})

Comment: Thanks, I understand already how these work with the DOM, see my edit

Comment: Ok, are you catching the 'myInput' in ngOnChanges() life cycle method?

Comment: refer this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhr94y. ngOnInit will be called once (it will be cached), ngOnChanges will be called multiple times

Answer (score 1):

[hidden] uses CSS to hide it on the page but using *ngIf removes it from the DOM so when it is shown it is reloaded rather than just made visible.

Comment: Thanks, I understand already how these work with the DOM, see my edit

Comment: @mindparse can you provide a code example of how you are loading the values in your child component? You might just need to add some load data code in the ngOnInit to load the new values?

Comment: @mindparse I have created a simple example here which works with *ngIf https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kitq4t?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html are you sure you are updating the passed in value?